# How can I use DB::select() result as object in my views?

Tags: php, fuelphp

So this is working:

```
DB::select()->from('images')->execute()->as_array();
```

But I don't like arrays in my views (2 extra letters) I want to use the object. How can I do that?

```
DB::select()->from('images')->as_object()->execute();
```

This is giving an error.

Comment: Have you tried with those?
// Will fetch the result as an associative array.
$result = DB::select()->from('images')->as_assoc()->execute();

// Will fetch the result as an object.
$result = DB::select()->from('images')->as_object()->execute();

// Will fetch the result as an Model_Users object.
$result = DB::select()->from('images')->as_object('Model_Images')->execute();

Comment: "This is giving an error." is a very unhelpful way of asking for help, what is the error given?

Comment: @MarcoPace How do you access Model_Images from ```$result = DB::select()->from('images')->as_object('Model_Images')->execute();```
The document said "Will fetch the result as an object" but i can't find the way to accesss that as model object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from my comment on the original question, any query that's executed will return a `Database_Result` object that can be foreached and should return stdClass objects for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`DB::select()->from('images')->as_object()->execute()->as_array();`

Comment: Actually no, adding it will make little difference as it failed without ->as_array() on the end - the statement will never be reached. Though he never gave the error so it's hard to know what triggered it in the first place.